# How do I re-factor references to static enum members

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

My code consists of references to enumeration in the following fashion.

```
Flowers { ROSE, SUNFLOWER }

import com.mycompany.Flowers;

class A {
    public void foo(...) {
        Flowers flower = Flowers.ROSE;
    }
}
```

I would like the above code to use static references to Flowers, the code would then look like

```
import static com.mycompany.Flowers.ROSE;

Flowers flower = ROSE;
```

How can I re-factor my code (using Eclipse) to use static references of enums instead of the normal referencing mechanism. Is there a way to tell Eclipse to modify all regular enum references to static references?

Comment: There is in IntelliJ (free edition) so I imagine it should be in eclipse as well.  It is likely to be an auto-fix if you can do it.

Comment: for idea it's alt+Enter on Flowers.ROSE.

Comment: @Vladimir: Alt+ENTER? That's for properties...?

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think it's a good idea to overuse static imports. Depending on the extent you're using them, it can increase the likelihood of a compiler error. (Say you had Color.ROSE and Flowers.ROSE). Obfuscating the enum makes it harder to read when there's a lot more logic. This similar to implementing an interface of constants (which is allowed but not conventional).

Answer (score 8):

That's probably not as proficient as you're looking for, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on the reference of a static object will statically import it (works for members and methods alike)... That way you can achieve your static imports one-by-one.

I'm interested too in other ideas, though

Comment: The above shortcut works fine, is there a way to automate this across all java files within the eclipse project.

Comment: I have so many constants like this and would love to see an automated solution, if possible

Comment: @user339108, if I realy realy want to do something like this, I typically write a short perl script to handle the change.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but would love to see if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: An other workaround is to define favorites in Eclipse for the most commonly used holders of static objects. That's a good solution, if you have a few enum classes with lots of enums and lots of references. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports

Comment: Hi Lukas - Thanks for the link its really helpful, but I am still not able to modify all the existing enum imports as static imports. How do I achieve this?

Comment: The biggest problem which I have is that I have a large number of enums which needs to be migrated as static imports. All of the above solutions help you to have a strategy of using static imports but not about migrating the existing ones. Kindly clarify

Comment: Well, why don't you search and replace? Write a very elaborate regular expression and then: good luck! :) I can't tell you more than I did. That's why I wrote `I'm interested too in other ideas, though`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in two simple steps:

- Use a find and replace maybe with a regular expression to change all the instances `Flowers.NAME` to just `NAME`.
- Then do a project wide 'Organize imports' like so:  Select the project in the package explorer and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (same keystroke as the single class version). Should work for packages, etc.. Bobs your uncle. (From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403569/can-you-organize-imports-for-an-entire-project-in-eclipse-with-a-keystroke)).

Comment: I have so many references like this in my project (its not just the NAME reference alone). I would like to know if there is a way to do this across all such references.

Answer (score 0):

Simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on the word `Rose` and you will see that it is statically imported.

Comment: I have many references like this in my project (its not just the NAME reference alone). I would like to know if there is a way to do this across all such references automatically