# How to add import statements in a java class programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a requirement to refactor nearly 5000 java classes in such a way that, its import statements need to be modified. Doing it manually by opening in Eclipse will take months time. So we need to automate it.

I have a piece of code to remove all the import statements from the class file, now I need to add the fresh imports by some way. Please share your thoughts and inputs.

I do have a new set of jars, from which classes will be used to organize the imports.

I have conflicts with multiple class files. Like classes with same name is there in different Utility packages. So user intervention is required most of the cases so that I can select the appropriate classes which need to be imported.

Let me know if there is any other way than the above one :)

Comment: In eclipse theres a shortcut Ctrl + Shift + O to add the imports, right? If you do it programmatically how would you know which class to import?

Comment: Since user interaction is required eclipse's organize import is not effective:(. 
And I can handle the user interaction through an "if else" code if there is any program for organize imports.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you organize imports for an entire project in eclipse with a keystroke?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403569/can-you-organize-imports-for-an-entire-project-in-eclipse-with-a-keystroke)

Comment: whats problem with ctrl+shift+o ?

Comment: I have conflicts with multiple class files. Like classes with same name is  there in different Utility packages. So user intervention is required most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

As Sweeper says, you can right-click on the source-folder, tipically `src/main/java`, and then `Source > Organize Imports`. This will remove the unused `imports` and add the ones required. User interaction is going to be needed, because if several classes were to conflict, you will have to choose the one you want.